# Добавить на страницу лоадер или прогресс выполнения задачи

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, freemarker

Есть `spring boot` сервер и одна страница на  `freemarker` - `index.flt`

На странице есть кнопка "Сгенерировать", которая запускает генерацию нескольких отчетов. При нажатии на нее вызывается метод контроллера

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generate/standart", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView generate(@RequestParam String name)
    throws NurException, IOException 
{
    ModelAndView index = new ModelAndView("index");
    billService.createPdfStandart(name);
    index.addObject("message", "Success");
    return index;
}
```

В методе вызывается сервис, который генерит отчеты.

Не вдаваясь в подробности: дергается селект, который возвращает, например, 100 значениий. На основании значений из селекта в цикле создается 100 отчетов, которые являются параметрами. Это занимает много времени, например, 10 минут. Я нажимаю "Сгенерировать" - запускается долгий процесс и страница в браузере висит, как-будто загружается.

Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Сгенерировать" появился лоадер или прогресс бар, который будет отображать процесс загрузки.

Я все делаю в цикле, поэтому хотелось бы показывать что-то наподобие `"загрузка 1\100"`, потом `5\100 99\100 100\100`. То есть на каждом шаге в цикле обновлять на странице элемент со значением или, в крайнем случае, вечный лоадер на время работы процесса.

Предполагаю, что потребуется ajax или jquery.

Где найти готовое решение ([вроде такого](http://joxi.ru/krDlk30f0p9Dzr)) или информацию о том как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Методы контроллера не должны блокировать выполнение веб-приложения. Такая функциональность делается на асинхронных запросах на backend. То есть по кнопке показали ajax loader и отправили запрос на сервер "Построить отчет" - он вам ответил "Строю" (посмотрите на аннотацию `@Async` в Spring Framework). Дальше по таймеру опрашиваете сервер о готовности отчетов. Как только получаете положительный ответ - прячете ajax loader.
Также при ответе на poll-запросы (о статусе выполнения задачи) можете возвращать мета-информацию о текущем состоянии обработки, типа, 1/100 - 5/100 - 96/100, как вы и хотите.